# Searching keywords in Preview: Don't automatically jump to first occurrence

Tags: macos, search, pdf-reader

This is driving me crazy. Whenever I search for a term in a pdf with Preview (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) it will jump to the very first occurrence of the search term in the *entire* document (!) automatically. I want it to *stay* on the current page and only jump when I do Find Next (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) or Find Previous (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>), respectively.

Can I make some settings changes to achieve this? The preferences menu is tiny and does not have that option.